# Convergence of $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x} \ln^{2}x \, \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that
$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x \, \text{d}x$$
Is convergent. My approach is
$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x \,  \text{d}x = \int_0^1 e^{-x}\ln^2 x \, 
\text{d}x + \int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x \, \text{d}x$$
For the second integral I've used the inequality $\ln x \leq x-1 < x$, so being $x\in[1,+\infty)$, it follows that $\ln^2 x < x^2$; so
$$\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x \, \text{d}x < \int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x}x^2 \, \text{d}x = 5e^{-1}$$

So my questions are:

(1) Is the estimation correct? I'm not so sure of $\ln^2 x < x^2$, I'm pretty sure it works in $[1,+\infty)$ but I would like to know if there is a way to estimate $\ln^2 x <x^2$.

(2) I've noticed that
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x=0$$
Is this enough to say that the integral in the interval $[1,+\infty)$ is convergent? If yes, how can I prove it? I'm suspicious because if the limit was $+\infty$ I could use comparison test, but in this case it doesn't give information so maybe the limit being $0$ isn't enough to prove the convergence.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Regarding (2): $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1/x = 0$ but $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \infty$.

Comment: Some people write "\ln^2x$ when they mean $\ln\ln x$ and some write that when the mean $(\ln x)^2.$ I think it would be better to pick one of those notations, depending on which you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first integral,
$\int \log^2(x) dx 
= x (\log^2(x) - 2 \log(x) + 2)
$
so
$\int_0^1 \log^2(x) dx 
= 2
$.

Since
$\dfrac1{e}
\le e^{-x}
\le 1
$
for
$0 \le x \le 1$,
we have
$\dfrac{2}{e}
\le \int_0^1 e^{-x}\log^2(x) dx 
\le 2
$.

For the second integral,
since $\log(x) < \log(1+x) \le x$
for $x \ge 1$,
and
$\int x^2 e^{-x} dx 
= -e^{-x} (x^2 + 2 x + 2)
$,
we have
$\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ln^2 x dx
\lt \int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x}x^2 dx
=\dfrac{5}{e}
$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not too hard to show that for values greater than $1$, $\ln^2x<x$ and to show $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x}{x}\,\mathrm dx$ is convergent is very easy (through integration by parts, for example). Can you give it a try from here?

Concerning your last statement "Is this enough to say...", the answer is NO. The fact that the limit goes to zero for $x$ going to infinity does not automatically warrant a convergent integral, counter example: $$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx$$